Background task crashing app when trying to schedule
I am trying to schedule and app refresh task under Swift 6 and iOS18 but the code crashes when trying to schedule the background task.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Here is the example that crashes when you hit
BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests

import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    
    let backgroundAppRefreshTask = "com.example.app.refreshTask"
    
    init() {
        registerBackgroundTasks()
        scheduleAppRefresh()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }

    func registerBackgroundTasks() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: backgroundAppRefreshTask, using: nil) { task in
            handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
    }

    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        // Handle the task
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests { taskRequests in
            if taskRequests.contains(where: { $0.identifier == backgroundAppRefreshTask }) {
                print("⚠️ Task Pending: '\(backgroundAppRefreshTask)' is already pending.")
                return
            }

            let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: backgroundAppRefreshTask)
            if let nextHour = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(minute: 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime) {
                request.earliestBeginDate = nextHour
            }

            do {
                try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
                print("✅ App refresh task '\(backgroundAppRefreshTask)' successfully scheduled.")
            } catch {
                print("❌ Failed to schedule app refresh task.")
            }
        }
    }
}



can you share crash logs?? one possible case could be that you forgot to add com.example.app.refreshTask under Permitted background task scheduler identifiers in info.plist

Works fine using swift 5, barfs using swift 6.  Identifiers are correct.  I took a screenshot of the crash I get when the scheduler is run 'BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests'
